# What's the by-the-rules difference between a Heavy Crossbow and a Large-Sized Light Crossbow?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm not particularly clear on how this is supposed to work, but it seems like a Large-Sized Light Crossbow is better in most respects.

Answer (score 10):

Using an inappropriately sized weapon applies a -2 penalty to hit, and raises the weapon by one 'category' (light->one-handed->two-handed->unusable). So, to use your example, a Large Light Crossbow, while it would do the same damage as a Heavy Crossbow, would have a penalty to hit and a shorter range. There's no good reason to do it.

Further, depending on your GMs interpretation of the RAW, it can be argued that an oversized crossbow *requires* two hands to shoot, and cannot be reloaded, as those tasks require one hand and two hands respectively with a properly-sized weapon.

Comment: Exactly, a heavy cross bow essentially *is* a 'large light crossbow'.  An unassisted person isn't capable of loading one.  That's why they have the ratchet/winch assisting devices for loading.